# How big of a deal is the state's attorney's office of cook county?

Tags: realism, the-good-wife

In the TV series *The Good Wife* Peter and Alicia Florrick are running for state's attorney at some point. A lot of effort goes into both of these campaigns:

1. Money: I assume paying for campaign handlers like Eli Gold or Johnathan Elfman costs tens of thousands dollars over several months.
2. the work of volunteers and campaign workers: Peter has about 30 depicted in several episodes, Alicia mentions a similar number
3. shady work: both campaigns employ so-called "trackers" (to film the respective opponents and those around them at embarrassing moments), people on Twitter to circulate rumors etc.

It seems to me, that although state's attorney might be an important position, and even a stepping stone for other offices, that the depiction of these campaigns are a bit excessive.

Are campaigns for counties this big really run in this fashion?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about real life politics rather than the movie itself

Comment: Actually this question is about how realistic the depiction of such a campaign is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are campaigns for counties this big really run in this fashion?

## Absolutely.

Kim Foxx, the current CCSA raised over $2,000,000 in campaign funds according to Fox News (via [**ChicagoTribune.com**](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/local/politics/ct-cook-county-states-attorney-race-met-1025-20161024-story.html))

> She has raised more than $174,000 since the start of July after bringing in more than $1.9 million in the first six months of the year, according to campaign records.

These posts are *highly* politicised and the Repulican/Democratic parties will get behind it and there is no shortage of volunteers and basic wage interns who will come out to work for candidates.

As for the *dirty tricks*, there is no doubt that there are "opposition" investigations and exposés but it's more likely that these are highly exagerated for TV/movie purposes.

Answer (score 3):

[Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_County_State%27s_Attorney):

> The Cook County State's Attorney functions as the district attorney
>   for Cook County, Illinois, and heads **the second largest prosecutor's
>   office in the United States. The office has nearly 900 attorneys and
>   1,600 employees, and has an annual operating budget of approximately
>   $131 million for fiscal year 2010.**
>
> The Assistant State’s Attorneys in
>   the Office prosecute all misdemeanor and felony crimes committed in
>   **Cook County, one of the largest counties in the nation** encompassing
>   nearly 1,000 square miles. In addition to direct criminal prosecution,
>   the State’s Attorney’s Office files legal actions to enforce child
>   support orders, protect consumers and the elderly from exploitation,
>   and assist thousands of victims of domestic violence every year.

Comment: See my edited question.